# HAProxy redirect to subdomain

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I am trying to redirect these:

- http://www.example.co.uk/blog/xyz?a=b
- https://www.example.co.uk/blog/xyz?a=b

to these:

- http://blog.example.co.uk/xyz?a=b
- https://blog.example.co.uk/xyz?a=b

But struggling with the documentation and the best way to do this.

*** Update ***

This is what I have got working at the moment. If I pass in:

- http://www.example.co.uk/blog?a=b

then this redirects to:

- http://blog.example.co.uk?a=b

... and the section of the config:

```
acl blog_page path_beg -i /blog
use_backend blog_site if blog_page
backend blog_site
reqrep        ^([^\ :]*)\ \/?(.*)\/blog\/?(.*)    \1\ /\2\3
redirect prefix http://blog.example.co.uk code 301
```

Comment: I have update my question to show what I have a the moment but thought this could be reduced to a simple redirection rather than creating a new ```backend``` server. (fyi:  the site blog.example.co.uk is hosted elsewhere and not controlled via this haproxy instance so just need to perform a redirect and then dns will perform the correct resolve)

Comment: Thank you for the update. Sometimes people incorrectly use the word "redirect" when they actually mean "forward," but you have not made that mistake. Yes, this can be reduced to a one-liner, in the frontend section, with HAProxy 1.6 and later.  I will provide an answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line in the frontend section will accomplish this rewrite and redirect.

Shown as multiple lines for clarity, **this must all appear on a single line** of your configuration:

```
http-request redirect 
        code 301 
        location https://blog.example.com%[capture.req.uri,regsub(^/blog,)]  
        if { hdr(host) -i www.example.com } { path_beg /blog }
```

If the host header matches www.example.com and path begins with blog, redirect to a location beginning with the literal string `https://blog.example.com` then concatenate a value derived by taking the request URI (path + query string) and using regex substitution to remove `/blog` from the beginning.

Verifying:

```
$ curl -v 'http://www.example.com/blog/posts?which=this&that=1'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to www.example.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /blog/posts?which=this&that=1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.example.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://blog.example.com/posts?which=this&that=1
```

The redirect location appears to be correct.

If you want to redirect http and https separately, you'd need two lines, each of them testing an additional condition to determine whether the original request was over http or https.

Using the `regsub()` converter requires HAProxy 1.6+.

Comment: Thank for the code and just found out we are running version 1.5.12 so; as you say, the ```regsub()``` fails

Comment: Also now been told that due to seo I need to retain the original url, is this possible?

Comment: Well, then, in that case, you want to configure the blog server as a backend, and forward the requests through the proxy to it, instead of redirecting.

Comment: Got around the `regsub()` issue with this;  

`http-request del-header x-blog-rewrite`  

`http-request add-header x-blog-rewrite %[url] if { path_beg /blog }`  

`http-request replace-header x-blog-rewrite ^/blog(/.*)?$ /\1 if { hdr_cnt(x-blog-rewrite) gt 0 }`  

Then used this;  

`%[hdr(x-blog-rewrite)]`  

instead of this;  

`%[capture.req.uri,regsub(^/blog,)]`